# About links of Imageview and button in iOS App Development

Tags: ios-simulator

I am linking the imageview and Button to my code but when I start my simulator to see how it works then after the launchscreen it is crashing.[My code where i have linked the imageview and button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLcZb.png)
[This is error its showing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvESi.png)
[Code log depicting the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S26AJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that it tried to link the button to a property called `askbutton`, which is obviously missing from your view controller class. Most probably you had an `@IBOutlet` for that button which you deleted from the code, but did not remove from storyboard. The easiest way to fix this is to remove all the links of the ask button from storyboard and re-establish them. This way you'll make sure everything will be setup properly.